Add additional file to MSIX artifacts output
In Visual Studio I have a .wapproj project. When it's build by Nuke, the output artifacts in resulted folder are installation files.

.msixbundle
Install.ps1
Add-AppDevPackage.ps1

And some other files required to install the app.
I want to add one additional static file (installation instruction txt file) so that when installation artifacts built, I would have .msixbundle, those two installation scripts and my txt file.
Seems like all the things I googled lead to my file packed inside .msixbundle and then available to read after the app is installed. But that is not what I try to achieve.

Would a post-build step work? Something like this question
